# Finding the number of values above a value and less than a value in a df column without using a loop

Tags: r

Consider the following:

```
df <- data.frame(X = c(5000, 6000, 5500, 5000, 5300))

count_above <- function(vector)
{
  counts <- vector()
  counts[1] <- 0
  for (i in 2:length(vector))
  {
    temp <- vector[1:i]
    counts <- c(counts, sum(temp < vector[i]))
  }
  return(counts)
}
```

This gives me the correct output:

```
count_above(df$X)
[1] 0 1 1 0 2
```

For instance, the (column) vector here is

```
5000
6000
5500
5000
5300
```

At the very top `5000`, there are no values above it. So this gives value `0`.

At the `6000`, there is one value which is above it and is less than `6000`: the `5000`. So this gives value `1`.

At the `5500`, there are two values above it, one of which is less than `5500`, so this gives value `1`, and so forth.

**Is there any way I can write this out without using a loop?**

Comment: Usually you want to avoid for loop and use vectorized function instead. However in this case for every row you need to compare i-1 values, and I don't think this can be vectorized much. Sometimes just keep for loop is OK. Wrap it with apply family may actual harm readability.

Comment: Several points in your functions can be improved though: 1. create the counts vector with fixed size instead of increase it in every step. 2. No need to create temp, just use vector[1:i] in place. 3. don't use reserved name as variable, like the parameter `vector`. 4. it should be vector[1:(i-1)]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Another approach, quite similar to aichao's solution (but a bit shorter)

```
X <- c(5000, 6000, 5500, 5000, 5300)
indices <- 1:length(X)
count_above <- colSums(outer(X, X, "<") & outer(indices, indices, "<"))
## [1] 0 1 1 0 2
```

**Edit (Performance):** Perhaps my idea was selected as the accepted answer because it is short and self-explaining code - but be careful to use it on large vectors! It's the slowest approach of all the solutions suggested here! Similar to that what dracodoc did, I also did a microbenchmark. But I used a random generated vector of 3000 values to get more significant run times:

```
count_above_loop <- function(v)
{
  counts <- integer(length = length(v))
  counts[1] <- 0
  for (i in 2:length(v))
  {
    counts[i] <- sum(v[1:(i-1)] < v[i])
  }
  return(counts)
}

count_above_outer <- function(X) {
  indices <- 1:length(X)
  colSums(outer(X, X, "<") & outer(indices, indices, "<"))
}

count_above_apply <- function(X) {
  sapply(seq_len(length(X)), function(i) sum(X[i:1] < X[i]))
}

X <- runif(3000)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(count_above_loop(X), 
                               count_above_apply(X),
                               count_above_outer(X), times = 10)

Unit: milliseconds
                 expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
  count_above_loop(X)  56.27923  58.17195  62.07571  60.08123  63.92010  77.31658    10  a 
 count_above_apply(X)  54.41776  55.07511  57.12006  57.22372  58.61982  59.95037    10  a 
 count_above_outer(X) 121.12352 125.56072 132.45728 130.08141 137.08873 154.28419    10   b
```

We see that the apply approach on a large vector and without the overhead of a data frame is slightly faster than the for-loop.

My outer product approach takes more than double the time.

So I would recommend to use the for-loop - it's also readable and faster. My approach might be considered if you want to have provable correct code (as this one-liner is quite near to a specification of the problem)

Comment: Thanks for the update. I should use a bigger random data set too. The tiny example size I used make the benchmark I did less informative.

Answer (score 6):

Consider a running conditional count with `sapply()`. Though this is still a loop, it is a vectorized method:

```
count_above <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(df)), 
                      function(i) sum(df[i:1, c("X")] < df$X[i]))
count_above
# [1] 0 1 1 0 2
```

Comment: it should be df[(i-1):1, c("X")]

Comment: Not necessarily the row just above it. See OP's third row of 5500 returns 1 since it looks at 5000 and 6000, the two above it (all values above).

Comment: I mean you should compare all rows above i with i, which means v[1:(i-1)] and v[i]. Including i didn't have error only because comparing v[i] < v[i] is FALSE. Conceptually it should be i-1.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: I should use bigger dataset for benchmark, the tiny dataset make the benchmark results a little bit misleading. See PatrickRoocks's update.

I just commented that for loop is not necessarily bad than apply family then I saw this.

I did a microbenchmark comparing a optimized for loop and the sapply method. for loop is 6 times faster. The sapply method is not a proper function, modifying it into a function taking a vector instead of assuming data frame columns could improve a little bit.

```
df <- data.frame(X = c(5000, 6000, 5500, 5000, 5300))

count_above <- function(v)
{
  counts <- integer(length = length(v))
  counts[1] <- 0
  for (i in 2:length(v))
  {
    counts[i] <- sum(v[1:(i-1)] < v[i])
  }
  return(counts)
}
count_above(df$X)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(count_above(df$X), sapply(seq_len(nrow(df)), function(i) sum(df[i:1, c("X")] < df$X[i])), times = 10)

Unit: microseconds
                                                                  expr
                                                     count_above(df$X)
 sapply(seq_len(nrow(df)), function(i) sum(df[i:1, c("X")] < df$X[i]))
     min      lq     mean   median      uq     max neval cld
  38.623  41.068  65.0722  55.0010  65.512 142.757    10  a 
 262.045 269.379 368.6231 339.2905 415.067 640.934    10   b
```

Update:

```
# modify Parfait's answer into a function, taking vector instead of data frame
count_above_2 <- function(v){
  counts <- sapply(seq_len(length(v)), 
    function(i) sum(v[i:1] < v[i]))
  return(counts)
}

X <- df$X

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(count_above(X), count_above_2(X), {indices <- 1:length(X); colSums(outer(X, X, "<") & outer(indices, indices, "<"))}, times = 100)

Unit: microseconds
                                                                                        expr
                                                                              count_above(X)
                                                                            count_above_2(X)
 {     indices <- 1:length(X)     colSums(outer(X, X, "<") & outer(indices, indices, "<")) }
    min      lq     mean  median      uq     max neval cld
 21.023 23.4680 39.02878 26.1565 35.4450 144.224   100  a 
 41.067 49.3785 67.06162 53.2900 70.1565 166.712   100   b
 37.646 40.0900 66.45059 53.0450 72.8455 258.623   100   b
```

For loop still wins.
Transfer a vector instead of `df$X` save time for all, so I give 3 solutions same vector to be comparable.
Parfait's answer is comparable with PatrickRoocks's.

Besides performance, there is a subtle point of correctness.

OP's function and Parfait's sum(v[i:1] < v[i]) give correct answer only because v[i] < v[i] is FALSE. By definition it should use v[1:(i-1)] < v[i].

My function can be written in a more concise version like this:

```
count_above <- function(v)
{
  counts <- integer(length = length(v))
  for (i in 1:length(v))
  {
    counts[i] <- sum(v[1:(i-1)] < v[i])
  }
  return(counts)
}
```

It looks better and give correct result. This also depend on v[1] < v[1] is FALSE. It is not necessarily wrong since it is only about the first row, though I would still prefer the longer but more obvious version.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach (still a loop because of `colSums`):

```
xg <- expand.grid(df$X,df$X)
o <- matrix(xg$Var1 < xg$Var2, nrow=length(x))
o[lower.tri(o)] <- FALSE
count_above <- colSums(o)
##[1] 0 1 1 0 2
```

This will most likely not be as efficient as Parfait's answer, but it is an alternative.